# Erro: Unrecognized escape sequence

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel

estou desenvolvendo um programa em c# para ler arquivos .xlsx e ta dando erro no caminho "path" na linha 9 desse arquivo e não sei o porque.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       static System.Data.DataSet GetExcelData(string Workbook)
        {
            DataSet SeleniumElementSet = new DataSet();
            var excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            var datatable = new System.Data.DataTable();
            string[] strrow = new string[2];
            string caminho = "C:Desktop\Dataset.xlsx";

            int rCnt = 0;
            int cCnt = 0;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range;

            xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open((AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + caminho + Workbook),
            0,true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, false, 1, 0);
            int worksheetcount = xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Count;
            //int wks = 1;
            for (int wks = 1; wks <= worksheetcount; wks++)
            {
                xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(wks);
                String datatablename = xlWorkSheet.Name;
                range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
                //Console.WriteLine(wks);

                var dt = new System.Data.DataTable(datatablename);

                int rowCount = range.Rows.Count;
                int colCount = range.Columns.Count;
                //int colCount = 3;
                string[] headers = new string[colCount];
                for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= colCount; cCnt++)
                {

                    headers[cCnt - 1] = (Convert.ToString((range.Cells[1, cCnt] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value2));
                    dt.Columns.Add(headers[cCnt - 1]);
                    //Console.WriteLine(headers[cCnt - 1]);
                }
                for (rCnt = 2; rCnt <= rowCount; rCnt++)
                {
                    var array = new object[colCount];

                    for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= colCount; cCnt++)
                    {
                        array[cCnt - 1] = (Convert.ToString((range.Cells[rCnt, cCnt] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value2));

                    }

                    dt.Rows.Add(array);


                }
                SeleniumElementSet.Tables.Add(dt);
            }
            xlApp.Quit();

            return SeleniumElementSet;
        }
    }
```

Comment: coloca `@"C:\Desktop\Dataset.xlsx"` ou `"C:\\Desktop\\Dataset.xlsx"`

Comment: Que erro está dando amigo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No caminho do arquivo está faltando uma barra depois dos dois pontos e você precisa 'escapar' as barras, pode fazer isso de duas formas:

```
string caminho = @"C:\Desktop\Dataset.xlsx";
```

ou

```
string caminho = "C:\\Desktop\\Dataset.xlsx";
```

Comment: encontrei em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1302864/unrecognized-escape-sequence-for-path-string-containing-backslashes

Comment: Removendo o comentário logo logo porque agora está certo ...

Comment: boa.. certinho, vlw amigo